# How to add two primary keys in realm model with react native

Tags: react-native, realm

I want to add unique ids in realm model.
I added one primary key in model. I have no idea about how to add two primary keys.

Comment: Give us some more information like the code that you have now

Answer (score 0):

Primary Key have to exist one in your table. Because It is used to distinguish item.
This is common usage among many databases. 
Normally, To use database in all the use cases like you, Databases have theirs method like index. It is possible to use index in realm database. See below.

```
const BookSchema = {
  name: 'Book',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id:    'int',    // primary key
    title: { type: 'string', indexed: true }, // index useable like primary key
    price: 'float'
  }
};
```